# How to change the report's default drop-down value?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have used *JasperReports Server 5.5* as the reporting module which runs on tomcat. When I add input controls, drop-downs are shown as below.

[image]

default value is --- in the drop-downs.

How to change the report's default drop down value(---) to All?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of multiselect parameter of Collection type (java.util.Collection)  you do not need to give "All" to select all the values in iReport as default value for that parameter by default it means all the values are selected.
But if the parameter is single select of String type then the query for input control in JasperReport Server will be: -

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (SELECT 'All Country' SHIPCOUNTRY FROM orders

 UNION

 SELECT DISTINCT SHIPCOUNTRY FROM orders) b
 ORDER BY SHIPCOUNTRY
```

iReport query for report where you will use parameter in where clause will be : -

```
SELECT SHIPCOUNTRY,SHIPCITY
FROM orders
WHERE ($P{p_shipcountry}='All' OR SHIPCOUNTRY=$P{p_shipcountry})
```

Where p_shipcountry is a parameter in iReport and it is single select of String (java.lang.String) type parameter and make the input control mandatory.

For more detail you can refer my [blog.](http://passionfordata.blogspot.in/2014/05/adding-all-in-jasperreport-input.html)

Comment: I just want to rename --- to All in the drop-down

Comment: I do not think so we can rename -- to All, after changing the input control query according to above you can  make the input control mandatory so you will not get -- in input control values.